# Recreate this chart in python - what type of chart is it?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization

I'm trying to recreate the chart from [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/g4uyfe/sleep_pattern_of_baby_36_months_oc/) on Reddit. How would I recreate a chart like this in python? What would you even call this type of chart?

The chart looks like this:

[image]

I tried [this similar approach](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3jhzcv/creating_a_sleep_log/cuqmbua/), but a bubble chart isn't quite what I'm looking for. Here's a simplified version of my data:

```
Date,Asleep,Awake
3/31,12:00 AM,5:00 AM
3/31,6:00 AM,8:30 AM
3/31,12:00 PM,2:45 PM
3/31,5:30 PM,8:30 PM
3/31,11:00 PM,11:59 PM
4/1,12:00 AM,4:30 AM
4/1,6:00 AM,9:00 AM
4/1,11:30 AM,2:00 PM
4/1,5:00 PM,9:00 PM
4/1,10:45 PM,11:59 PM
4/2,12:00 AM,2:30 AM
4/2,3:00 AM,8:00 AM
4/2,10:30 AM,2:00 PM
4/2,5:00 PM,10:00 PM
4/3,12:00 AM,8:30 AM
4/3,11:00 AM,3:00 PM
4/3,6:00 PM,9:00 PM
4/3,10:30 PM,11:59 PM
4/4,12:00 AM,9:00 AM
4/4,10:30 AM,12:00 PM
4/4,3:30 PM,5:00 PM
4/4,8:00 PM,10:30 PM
4/4,11:00 PM,11:59 PM
```

Comment: The way I see it, this is sort of bar chart, with `bottom` option. But some tweaks are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you part of the way...

#### Convert to proper types

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.radd('2020/'), format='%Y/%m/%d')
df['Asleep'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Asleep) - pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()
df['Awake'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Awake) - pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()
```

#### `vlines`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.vlines(df.Date, df.Asleep, df.Awake)
```

From here, you need to figure out how to format the axes and thicken the lines.  That's more matplotlib than I want to deal with this morning.

[image]